# Variable color webpage with SASS and ExpressionEngine

Tags: html, css, sass, expressionengine

I set up just a static page on my computer using SASS for the styles, and used a variable called `$productColor` throughout the styles. It's used for a bunch of different stuff like banner background colors, header colors, and link colors.

Now I moved the page to our server, on ExpressionEngine. I would like to have an ExpressionEngine field, so for each entry, a different color can be chosen, and that color will appear on the page.

Now I don't really know how to go about this. I don't even know how or if I can put a sass file on my server and get it automatically compiled into a css file. Anyways, any suggestions?

Comment: You're showing a different color for each item on a page? Don't regenerate/send css, just create a list of colors and assign each item on of the colors.

Comment: No, everything on the page is a single color. But I want that color to be different depending on which ExpressionEngine entry is being generated. @Matt R

Answer (score 0):

just define all colors in classes, and have a dropdown with the class names.
then in your template do something like this

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="{my_chosen_color}">
--- 
</body>
</html>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```